# Use Raspberry Pi as keyboard/mouse output to control server

Tags: usb, remote, keyboard, gadget

I want to connect to a RPi thought LAN (possibly with VNC) and have it controlling a server that is connected to the RPi by USB.

Basically the RPi would have to send every keystroke/mouse movement to the server using the USB emulating the keyboard/mouse.

(I intend to gather the server image by using a VGA to USB card connected to the RPi, but that part seems simple).

Is this possible? What packages do you propose?

Mind that I can't install anything in the server (I want to control the server when it boots, not when I'm already booted, for that part I just SSH into the server and bypass the RPi).

Also, I don't need high performance, I just want to be able to control the server in case it doesn't boot by some reason or in case I need to change some BIOS setting and I don't want to be carrying a monitor and keyboard around with me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the Raspberry Pi Zero , Zero W , Model A and Compute Module can act as USB device. Other models can **not** act as USB device. This is a hardware limitation which cannot be worked around in software.

You will not be able to make the Pi act as PS/2 keyboard or mouse. Not with the GPIO pins, that is.

Here is a guide for turning the  Pi Zero **into an USB keyboard/mouse** 
using ConfigFS :

http://isticktoit.net/?p=1383

Comment: I see. I did find a project aiming to do that. It uses both a RPi B and a Zero, for what I know exactly for the purpose you describe: https://github.com/Fmstrat/diy-ipmi

Answer (score 2):

The Raspberry Pi 4 has OTG capabilities on its USB-C Port. You can free that up by powering the board using the GPIO pins.

Since the Pi already has a camera input, you probably get a better picture with something inputting video to the camera head. There are several boards on Ali express that do that (search HDMI to CSI-2, if you really need VGA, you could use a VGA to HDMI adapter). There are multiple examples out there on how to incorporate a the camera input on a website. Among others the OctoPi software does that so you can remotely view your 3D printer working.

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking to control a windows 10 computer with a raspberry pi4, as a mouse and keyboard. I already have the power thing handled, with a usb power blocking but data through connector.  I am just looking for the code to do this.

I am looking to put coordinates in, and click on the location, then type in information received at the raspberry pi.  I am hoping micropython or circuit python can do it.

Thanks,

Steve C.